# SVNKit Trilead SSH Error - Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot negotiate, proposals do not match

Tags: eclipse, svn, trilead-ssh

Recently, the sshd_config file on our SVN server had to be modified due to security reasons and now we cannot connect to SVN via Eclipse using SSH.  The only key exchange methods and MAC methods offered by the SVNKit Trilead library have been removed as options from the sshd_config file and cannot be put back.

I've found this resource at the SVNKit site https://support.tmatesoft.com/t/svn-e210002-svnkit-doesnt-connect-to-remote-repository/2480/15 which is much the same issue I'm experiencing.

Stacktrace

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Key exchange was not finished, connection is closed.
at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.KexManager.getOrWaitForConnectionInfo(KexManager.java:92)
at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.getConnectionInfo(TransportManager.java:231)
at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:769)
... 40 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot negotiate, proposals do not match.
at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.KexManager.handleMessage(KexManager.java:413)
at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.receiveLoop(TransportManager.java:765)
at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager$1.run(TransportManager.java:480)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

I've been trying to manually patch the Trilead library but have been unsuccessful.  There aren't many comments in the classes and pretty hard to follow.

If anyone has any idea of how to address this issue or even another way to SSH into SVN from Eclipse it would really be appreciated.  I've been trying to figure this out for almost two weeks.  This is the first time I've asked a question on StackOverflow.  Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually, this error is happening when I attempt to SSH into SVN via Eclipse using SVNKit 1.8.14 connector.  There isn't any code other than this stacktrace and the Trilead library (which is part of the SVNKit plugin in Eclipse).  The trilead library is comprised of many classes.  I guess one big question is can an Eclipse plugin even be manually modified and recompiled?  I've definitely screwed up my environment a bit trying to do so.